# GridSearchCV did not find the best parameter with random forest

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

As I understand the `GridSearchCV` should find the best parameter for model based on average `cross_val_score()` evaluation (please see a description of best_score_ result field [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)).

However I get a such `max_depth` that looks not optimal. Say, if I pass `max_depth=2` manually I get a little better result then the result returned by GridSearchCV where `2` is in list of `max_depth` grid. The GridSearchCV, however, find that `8` is better than `2` for `max_depth`.

When I manually test the result of found 'best' max_depth parameter I find that it's not best.

Please, could you explain me why could GridSearchCV find parameter with 'accuracy' result worse then I get with `cross_val_score` with a first arbitrary parameter?

For details, please, look to the code below.

**UPDATE.** I have updated the code having added the parameter random_state for `RandomForestClassifier` (as Nain tell me kindly). Now scores are very close but not exactly same. Why aren't they same?..

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

DATA_LEN = 500
NUM_CLASSES = 3
NUM_VARS = 20

np.random.seed(0)

# data generation (some feature rows are equal to target y, some of these rows are random)

y = np.random.choice(NUM_CLASSES, DATA_LEN)

xs = []

for j in range(DATA_LEN):
    row = []
    for i in range(NUM_VARS):       
        rand_int = np.random.choice(NUM_CLASSES)

        if j < int(DATA_LEN / (i + 2)):
            row.append(y[j])
        else:
            row.append(rand_int)

    xs.append(row)

X = np.array(xs).reshape(DATA_LEN, -1)

# predict: cross_val_score with max_depth=2 and max_depth=8 (the last one is found by GridSearchCV)

np.random.seed(0)
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_depth=2, random_state=0)
clf.fit(X, y)
np.random.seed(0)
# average accuracy is '0.579718326935'
print np.average(cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=5, scoring='accuracy')) 

np.random.seed(0)
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, max_depth=5, random_state=0) 
clf.fit(X, y)
np.random.seed(0)
# average accuracy is '0.596127702566' which is not exactly the same as best score '0.59799999999999998'
print np.average(cross_val_score(clf, X, y, cv=5, scoring='accuracy'))

grid_params = {'max_depth': range(2, 20)}
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=0)

np.random.seed(0)
clf_searcher = GridSearchCV(clf, grid_params, scoring='accuracy', cv=5)
clf_searcher.fit(X, y)

# outputs best score '0.59799999999999998'
print 'best_score=', clf_searcher.best_score_
# outputs "best_params= {'max_depth': 5}""  
print 'best_params=', clf_searcher.best_params_
```

Comment: The thing is that you are not setting the `random_state` in your classifier. In that case, even though you have set the numpy seed but that doesn't guarantee that the folds will be the same in each case. Pass the seed as the value to the `random_state` parameter and check the result again

Comment: @Nain Are you sure or this is your hypothesis?

Comment: @Nain It looks like your idea is right, at least it seems working. Now GridSearchCV finds better average cross score, but for some reason it is rounded not fully equal to cross score returned by cross_val_score with found max_depth: grid_search_cv get me 0.598, but cross_val_score returns 0.596127702566 (very closely, but not exactly)...

Comment: You are still missing the `random_state` in the final clf you send to GridSearchCV. With this, I can confirm that the results are exact same. Only thing I could not find it why grid_search is returning a truncated score for when the arrays are exactly equal.

Comment: @sergzach but the difference is negligible.

Comment: Had it been something `0.6` instead of `0.596`, I would have given that a look but if the difference is after two decimal points, then it hardly matters

Comment: @VivekKumar I'm sorry, it was in my code, I forgot to update the part of code in the question. Now I've updated it.

Comment: @Nain I partially agree with you. But it is the test. If I miss a detail, why two numbers are not exactly the same, it could be a more serious error on working cases. The difference could stay more because of two 'slightly' different algorithms. The difference is significant, it's about 0.2%. Two much to count someone's money.

Comment: But this is more of a floating point precision issue. I would suggest doing one more thing though this isn't totally logical but still try this. Instead of setting seed everytime, do this at the start `seed=np.random.seed(0)` and pass this as `random_state=seed`

Comment: @Nain But `np.random.seed(0)` does not return a value (so, None is a return value). What do you mean, why should I pass None as random_state?

Comment: Ohh, my bad. It was meant to be like this `seed=0`. Then `np.random.seed(seed)` and `random_state=seed`

Comment: @Nain Nothing changes. Yes, you are right, `np.random.seed()` everywhere is redundant.

Comment: @sergzach I don't know what else might the problem be then.

Comment: As I said, by looking at the `cv_results_` of gridsearchcv for `split0_test_score`, `split1_test_score` I can confirm that the values are infact exactly equal (to the last precision point). They are just not equal when the mean is taken in gridsearchcv. The reason why gridsearchcv truncates or round off the results are not known. But maybe you can get the answer from their github page. Post this question as an issue there.

Comment: @VivekKumar Thank you! It's a very useful remark.

Comment: @VivekKumar If you want a point you could answer the question. I think it's enough for now.